# Statement from investment bank changed after filing - Do I need to amend?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, capital-gains-tax

My investment bank, a big one, which we'll call "Bob's Investment Bank" for paranoia reasons, sent me my end of year statement in early February, 2019. My wife and I filed our taxes using the numbers that were on that statement for form 8949, and we've already received our refund. However, Bob's sent us an amended statement today that shows the following (dollar amounts obfuscated by letter codes for consistency)

- Proceeds:

  - **Filed amount:** $AAAA.43
  - **Amended amount:** $AAAA.75
- Net Gain or Loss:

  - **Filed amount:** $BBBB.43
  - **Amended amount:** $BBBB.75

My illustration above attempts to show that the whole dollar amounts didn't change, but only the partial dollar amounts did, but a value of $0.32.

Now for my questions:

- *Is this something to worry about?*
- *Related: Do I need submit an amended return?*

Comment: A tax return will change very little, if at all, because of a 32 cent increase in capital gains.  At worst, it rounds the cap gain up $1 and when you multiply that by your tax bracket, it's highly unlikely that it changes the amount owed.  And even if it incurs  $1  of add'l taxes due, the IRS has better things to do than chase people for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you used tax software (or an online service) to complete your taxes, then enter the new numbers into your form without saving. See what changes. It is possible that nothing changes because of all the rounding.

If the amount of the refund changed, then use the amended return feature of the software.

If you didn't use tax software, then your calculations may be a bit harder because multiple calculations might be impacted.

It is unlikely that a $0.32 change will make a big difference, but you might be at a weird edge case.